# Two workflows running on a Library with Check in Check out

Tags: 2013, workflow, document-library, designer-workflow, check-in

I have two workflows on my Document Library that has Check in/Check out, my first workflow works fine, my second workflow won't work if I create a new document from a content type - it will work if I drag & drop or upload a document.

First workflow:

[image]

Second workflow (the document is checked in at the end of the workflow):

[image]

Does the second workflow have to wait for the first workflow to complete?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Workflows that are set to start on create or on change will start simultaneously. If the workflow is not starting, it is either that 1) the workflow wasn't added to the list, 2) the workflow was added but the trigger isn't correct (not set to start on create / change),  or 3) because the workflow is failing on start.

If you go to the list (viewed w/ the default view), then click the ellipses (...) next to the item, you can then select 'Workflow' and see which workflows were started (and if there was an error) as well as which workflows can be manually started (assuming the 'allow users to manually start workflow' option is checked).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Since writing this question I've changed the workflows by combining them into one, thinking that having two workflow running at the same time was the problem.  It now works correctly if I upload/drag&drop a document but the workflow at times takes around 6 min. to complete when I create a new document from a content type. This causes a bit of an issue for the client since the document is checked out during this period by the workflow.  Have you come across something similar?

Comment: Workflow performance can be cause by a number of things, so you'll probably have to do a bit of debugging/logic work. A few questions to answer for your troubleshooting:

1) Is the workflow starting immediately or is it taking a lot of time?
2) Are you writing to/reading from workflow history/task list? These can cause performance issues when they get large
3) Is there a particular stage in the workflow that is taking time? a web service call, a document action, etc?
...

Comment: ...If is still an issue that can't be resolved in tracking down those problems, you may have some availability issues elsewhere in your setup (app server (or wherever you run your workflow manager) bandwidth